# Should i use StartService or StartForegroundService for API >= 26?

Tags: java, android, service

I'm a bit confused because i read some posts where i'm supposed too use `ContextCompat.StartForegroundService();` if the API is >= 26.

Now I still just use **StartService** and it works even though i'm supposed to get an `IllegalStateException` on an API >= 26 ( current api on phone is 27) according to this post.

https://medium.com/mindorks/mastering-android-service-of-2018-a4a1df5ed5a6

> I know Service is an old concept. Let me assure you we will not discuss the basics and we will learn the recent changes made to the service layer in Android 8.0+, we will solve the mystery of famous **IllegalStateException** and RemoteServiceException. This article is not a conventional way of understanding services, hang tight till you can.

So my question is if i should change  `startForeGroundService` or just keep `startService` for API >=26?

**My Class that handles my Service connection:**

```
/**This establishes the connection to the MediaPlayerService. */
public static ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MediaPlayerService.MusicBinder binder = (MediaPlayerService.MusicBinder)service;
        mediaPlayerService = binder.getService();
        mediaPlayerService.musicBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mediaPlayerService.musicBound = false;
    }
};

/**This is called to start the MediaPlayerService. */
private static Intent mediaPlayerServiceIntent = null;
public static void startMusicService(Context c) {

    /*mediaPlayerServiceIntent binds our connection to the MediaPlayerService. */
    mediaPlayerServiceIntent = new Intent(c, MediaPlayerService.class);
    c.bindService(mediaPlayerServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    c.startService(mediaPlayerServiceIntent);
    mServiceIsActive = true;
}

/**This is called to stop the MediaPlayerService. (onDestroy) */
public static void stopMusicService(Context c) {

    if (mediaPlayerServiceIntent == null)
        return;
    c.unbindService(serviceConnection);
    c.stopService(mediaPlayerServiceIntent);
    mediaPlayerServiceIntent = null;

    mediaPlayerService = null;
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Main.startMusicService(getApplicationContext());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

startService will not work for api >=26

You can change your service to foreground service with help of following code. It will show the notification.

```
private void runAsForeground(){
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Notification notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentText(getString(R.string.isRecording))
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

for more reference - https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/effective-foreground-services-on-android_11.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

**another way (not recommended.. target sdk must be 26 or less)**

```
public static void startService(Context context, Class className) {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(context, className);
            restartServiceIntent.setPackage(context.getPackageName());
            PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            if (alarmService != null) {
                alarmService.set(
                        AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 500,
                        restartServicePendingIntent);
            }
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, className);
            context.startService(i);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MyLog.e(TAG, "startService: ", e);
    }
}
```

Call by

```
 startService(context,MediaPlayerService.class);
```

Comment: So i should use startService for api < 26  and startForeGroundService for api >=26 ?

Comment: And what about bindService? Do i keep it too communicate with the service?

Comment: try my updated answer.. it will work for both without startForeGroundService

Comment: For some reason i can't bind the service if i use startForeGroundService?

Comment: why you need target sdk 28? may I know the reason for using?

Comment: I want to support newer device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194521/discussion-between-ranjith-kumar-and-vince).